# iOS Realm readOnly causes empty result

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

I have a little problem with realm setting `readOnly` to `true` in the configuration. I am using Swift but I am using the normal `Realm.framework` ... Maybe this causes the error but I don't think so. (I am using it because I don't want to refactor my whole code...)

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

I tried this:

```
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("database", ofType: "realm")
        {
            //Alternative:  or move the file from the app bundle into a writable location
            var config = RLMRealmConfiguration()
            config.path = path
            config.readOnly = true

            do {
                try self.realm = RLMRealm(configuration:config)
            } catch {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
```

I also tried this:

```
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("database", ofType: "realm")
        {
            //Alternative:  or move the file from the app bundle into a writable location
            var config = RLMRealmConfiguration()
            config.path = path
            config.readOnly = true

            RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)

            do {
                try self.realm = RLMRealm(configuration: RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration())
            } catch {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
```

Both of them fail every time. (Printing: "Error") I figured out that the problem is that readOnly is set to true. I got both snippets working by setting `readOnly` to false. 
Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

I printed the Error and it is:

> Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/NR/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/NR/AppName.app/database.realm'"
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/NR/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/NR/AppName.app/database.realm,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/NR/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/NR/AppName.app/database.realm',
>   Error Code=2}

Comment: Can you print the exception instead? It might yield more information on what's the problem. `print(error)` in the catch.

Comment: @andreamazz I edited my question. (It was stupid that I didn't print it. :D )

Comment: If I read the error I start to think that he can't find the realm database. But this can't be because if I set readOnly to false there is no error. This is strange.

Comment: When you load it with read-write the data is there?

Comment: Exactly. This the strange thing.
I made some research an found this: 
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2746
He had a similar problem but he fixed it by setting the default configuration. But this didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, this may be a typo, but at the bottom of your error message, you've got 'databse.realm' (Missing an a). Are you sure all of the file paths you're using are correct?

Comment: @TiM I changed the name of the databaste so it is easier to understand, but thanks :) (I edited the error message) Yes the file path has to be correct. If I run the exact same code but set readOnly = false it works like charm.

Answer (score 2):

Okay guys I have no idea what happened but it works now.

I made a sample project with the database of their database and an object for their database and tried my code and it worked. (Both of them)

This confused me pretty much and I thought maybe my database is damaged or the object is wrong. I replaced their database in the sample project with my database and used my object and surprise it worked...

So I just deleted my database in my normal project (as I did 1000 times before) and added it again. I just put it on the top of my project structure and tried it again and it is working now...